# Axios post from React to PHPmailer

Tags: php, axios

I want to first get my code out there, then I will discuss my thought process.  I know there are a few older posts related to this, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

First my handleSubmit :

```
handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData();

if (this.state.file != undefined) {
  formData.append('file', this.state.file);
}
formData.append("name", this.state.name);
formData.append("email", this.state.email);
formData.append("message", this.state.message);
const config = {
  headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}

return post(*removed*, {formData}, config).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
}
```

and my PHP looks like:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

$name = $data['name'];
$email = $data['email'];
$message = $data['message'];

     if ( empty($name) OR empty($message)) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
    exit;
}
```

Now for some extra information.  1) As the code currently stands, I get a 400 response because it is not sending meaningful data, but it is sending data. 2) I know its posting because I do not get a 403. 3) If I set the variables for name,email, and message it will correctly send an email with the variables I have set.  4) I have also tried to use "set" instead of "append" but there is no change.

I believe that I am not correctly handling the data that PHP is receiving or that I am not sending the correct data from React.  I have found multiple other examples which show that what I have should work so I'm a bit at a loss here.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you using `FormData` if your PHP expects JSON? If you want to post a file via `multipart/form-data`, your PHP should be reading from `$_POST` and `$_FILES`, not `php://input`

Comment: @Phil I am currently using FormData because I want to set it up to also send an attachment at a later time, but did not want to complicate things at present.  My error could be that I have this working for my node server and I just tried to get this to work (for Bluehost sake) to uncomplicate how my Bluehost site is currently being served.  I am comfortable with JavaScript but not so much PHP.  Thank you for what you have currently stated, I will see if I can get it to work.